# How to get task scheduler history using c# based on daterange

Tags: c#

I need to use this method `TaskEventLog(string taskName = null, int[] eventIDs = null, int[] levels = null, DateTime? startTime = default(DateTime?), string machineName = null, string domain = null, string user = null, string password = null)` how can i use this any syntax or example for date range. My requirement is to get history log of scheduler based on daterange. right now i am able to get all the history at once by using `TaskEventLog(string taskPath)` method but i want based on daterange like last 24hrs run history...